# Where is my Azure ADO token stored locally?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

Looking in my machine nuget config I can see my ADO feed is registered, but there's no ADO token in it:

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
    <add key="dev.myfeed.com" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myfeed/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

Running a `dotnet restore` on my project successfully downloads a package which only exists in this feed, and I can't understand how it succeeds? The feed requires a token to authenticate against, and there's no token in my machine NuGet.config file. Has it retrieved the token from somewhere else?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities for this problem, and I need to confirm some more information with you. 1. Are you using a hosted agent or a private agent? 2. Could you be sure that the package only exists in the feed `dev.spektrix.com`? Try to check it in the nuget.org. 3. Have you added some nuget authentication tasks to your pipeline? Would you mind share the build definition in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has it retrieved the token from somewhere else?

The credentials are stored in **[Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#azure-artifacts-credential-provider)**. The Azure Artifacts Credential Provider automates the acquisition of credentials needed to restore NuGet packages as part of your .NET development workflow. We need to install the latest .NET Core SDK and **credential provider** first when we [use dotnet with Azure Artifacts feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=azure-devops).

Here is my sample when I run dotnet restore and verify with credential provider. I need to open a browser and sign in my account:
[image]

Comment: Hmm where is your Credential Provider saved? I've tried deleting it from mine and it still works so I'm not sure the token is saved within some file of the provider?

Comment: I can find it in C:\Users\User\.nuget\plugins. Please refer to this [document](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#manual-installation-on-windows). Can you try dotnet nuget push command? Sample: dotnet nuget push --interactive --source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/_packaging/test1/nuget/v3/index.json" --api-key az C:\Users\User\Downloads\test1.nupkg   . This command will publish a package from local to Azure Artifacts. It will also prompt you to log in. If I do not install Azure Artifacts Credential Provider, I will see a 401 error.

Comment: You can also try to delete the packages folder under C:\Users\User\.nuget. Run --dotnet restore --interactive and then check whether the package stored in azure artifacts appears in the packages.

Comment: @FBryant87 Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Thanks Walter I didn't realise I had this Azure Artifacts Credential Provider installed (I had another provider installed also). In fact I don't remember installer it so I wonder if it came with something else!